# Creating JSplitPane with 3 panels

Tags: java, swing

I would like to create a window, with 3 jPanels, separated by splitPane-s. The left, and the right one should be resizable by the user, and the one in the middle should fill the remaining space.

I've created it, but if I move the first splitPane, then the second one is also moving. And I'm not sure, if I use the best method for what I want.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class MyWindow extends JFrame {

    public MyWindow() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel centerPanel2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();

        JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, centerPanel);
        JSplitPane sp2 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, centerPanel2, rightPanel);

        centerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        centerPanel.add(sp2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing looks pretty weird to me i.e adding the `centerPanel` to the split pane, then adding the split pane to the `centerPane`. Not sure, but I think that the latter negates the former.

All you need to do is add the first split pane to the second split pane.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyWindow extends JFrame {

    public MyWindow() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, centerPanel);
        JSplitPane sp2 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, sp, rightPanel);

        this.add(sp2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new MyWindow();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sort of. The left pane can only be resized as far as the 2nd divider. The right pane on the other hand can shrink all the way to the far left boundry of the far left panel. This is a semi-solution, but isn't really the correct way to do it.

Comment: That's almost it. All you need to do ist set the minimum size of `sp` to the divider location + 2 * divider size + 1, that seems to do the job. I didn't bother to dig deeper into why that's the case, but it fixes the bug from @searchengine27's comment.
So you could either write a new component for that or simply create an anonymous class for `sp`.
Note that this only prevents the divider to shrink the left panel. Another solution would be to resize the right component. I don't see how that is possible though.

Comment: Minimum size divider location + divider size worked fine for me. I added a property listener to `sp` instead of an anonymous class.