# put two vertical JSplitPane on a frame java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jsplitpane

I am a new java programmer and I use stackoverflow since my begin. I code a little "game", and it is a text-based game. Well, i begin a graphical interface, to case the text, and i would have this configuration

[image: first image]

Basically, it is a double separation, with 3 horizontals elements. Actually, I have this:

[image: second image]

and i want a separation

[image: third image]

I have tried to put an other split pane on the top of the first one, like this:

```java
package sample;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Fenetresaisie extends JFrame {
    public static class Fenetre {
        public final static int HT = 1024;
        public final static int LG = 758;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JFrame F = new JFrame("CORONAZE");
            F.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            F.setSize(HT, LG);
            F.setVisible(true);

            F.addWindowListener(new gestionFenetre());

            ImageIcon icone = new ImageIcon("images.jpg");

            JLabel image = new JLabel(icone);

            JTextField textField = new JTextField();
            textField.setFont(new Font("Terminal", Font.BOLD, 30));
            textField.setForeground(Color.RED);
            textField.setBackground(Color.black);

            textField.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {

                public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
                     textField.getText();
                     e.getKeyChar();
                }
            });

            JLabel label = new JLabel(">texte de l'histoire ici<");
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setForeground(Color.green);
            label.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            panel.add(label);

            JSplitPane topJSplitPane = new JSplitPane( JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, label, textField);
          //  topJSplitPane.setDividerLocation(400);


            JSplitPane bottomJSplitPane = new JSplitPane( JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, topJSplitPane, textField );
            //i added it to have a double separation, but it give 2 sticked splitpane
            F.add(topJSplitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            F.add(bottomJSplitPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            F.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    static class gestionFenetre extends WindowAdapter {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives me two sticked splitpane :-/

[image: fourth image]

Can you help me please? I hope you understand my message, because I learn English. Contact me below if you want a next phase to this issue, thanks! ^^  Here is the actual graphical test java class:

```
package sample;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


class Fenetresaisie extends JFrame {

    public static class Fenetre {
        public final static int HT = 1024;
        public final static int LG = 758;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JFrame F = new JFrame("CORONAZE");
            F.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            F.setSize(HT, LG);
            F.setVisible(true);

            F.addWindowListener(new gestionFenetre());

            ImageIcon icone = new ImageIcon("images.jpg");

            JLabel image = new JLabel(icone);

            JTextField textField = new JTextField();
            textField.setFont(new Font("Terminal", Font.BOLD, 30));
            textField.setForeground(Color.RED);
            textField.setBackground(Color.black);

            textField.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {

                public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
                     textField.getText();
                     e.getKeyChar();
                }

            });



            JLabel label = new JLabel(">texte de l'histoire ici<");
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setForeground(Color.green);
            label.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            panel.add(label);

            JSplitPane topJSplitPane = new JSplitPane( JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, label, textField);
            topJSplitPane.setDividerLocation(400);


           // JSplitPane bottomJSplitPane = new JSplitPane( JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, topJSplitPane, textField );
            //i added it to have a double separation, but it give 2 sticked splitpane
            F.add(topJSplitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
           // F.add(bottomJSplitPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            F.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    static class gestionFenetre extends WindowAdapter {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One issue is that you add one `JSplitPane` into the other (which is correct) but then also add both to your `JFrame` (this is the mistake). So, only add the SplitPane, which contains the other one -> `F.add(bottomJSplitPane)`. This might fix your issue. If not, look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25593985/11441011) which is exactly your use case.

Comment: Additionally, your class `Fenetresaisie` does not need to extend `JFrame`, if you use a default `JFrame` then anyways.

Comment: 1) I guess the pending edit already does this, but in the future if you post links use the format `[Text to display](link url)`. 2) Use [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/), your inner class `gestionFenetre` should start with an uppercase letter as is standard for class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote in your question

> I am a new java programmer and I use stackoverflow since my begin

I really think that the way to learn *Swing* programming is to follow a learning curve that starts with the basics and gradually progresses. Everybody has his preferred way to learn, for example by attending a course or watching a video or reading a book. Personally I prefer books. If you do too, then I can recommend a few.

You also wrote in your question

> I code a little "game"

I would say that is a very ambitious project for a beginner. While I'm sure that there are people who learn best by starting off with ambitious projects, I would say they are in the minority.

That said, the key to correctly implementing your GUI is having a deep understanding of how *Swing* works, in particular [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [`Component`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) sizes as well as at what point in the code can you set those `Component` sizes.

The below code will initially display your desired GUI, since I understand, from your question, that that is what you are trying to accomplish now.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class WindowCapture extends WindowAdapter implements Runnable {
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JLabel  label;
    private JSplitPane  splitPane;
    private JSplitPane  topPane;

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.WindowAdapter
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent event) {
        int height = event.getWindow().getHeight();
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(0.7);
        double high = height * 0.7;
        height = (int) Math.rint(high);
        high = height * 0.8;
        height = (int) Math.rint(high);
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(event.getWindow().getWidth(), height));
    }

    private JTextField createBottomPane() {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.setFont(new Font("Terminal", Font.BOLD, 30));
        textField.setForeground(Color.RED);
        textField.setBackground(Color.black);
        return textField;
    }

    private JSplitPane createSplitPane() {
        splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, createTopPane(), createBottomPane());
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(0.4);
        return splitPane;
    }

    private JSplitPane createTopPane() {
        label = new JLabel(">texte de l'histoire ici<");
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setForeground(Color.green);
        label.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        topPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
                                            label,
                                            new JPanel());
        topPane.setDividerLocation(0.9);
        return topPane;
    }

    public void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Window Capture");
        frame.addWindowListener(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.add(createSplitPane());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Start here!
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new WindowCapture());
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture of the running app.

[image: fenetre]

Comment: ... waw... first: Thanks a lot to answer my question! and ...thats all i want :-)  BTW: i learn coding with many tutorials and books, and forums. And i code this because it is a "self tutorial": i have found this idea of "project", and i have to complete it. Each part of the code is a new concept to introduce! it is not a serious project ;-)! And i find this part of code very interesting! It is a lot of new concepts again, but I would study it later! And thanks a lot again, for your tips and your code! long live to forums ;-)